# Can I use any dojo, dijit or dojox api in my mobile web application ?

Tags: dojox.mobile

This may be a novice question. Can I use any dojo, dijit or dojox api in my mobile web application ?

-Have all the API been tested on variety of devices ? Do we have any reference document listing out the findings ?

-Lets say a particular widget is available in both dijit and dojox.mobile. What are the guidelines around choosing one of these (At a high level the choice is obviously dojox.mobile. But is there a guideline on how I can choose API for use in my application ?)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use any dojo, dijit or dojox api in my mobile web application ?

No. Some dijit parts doesn't work when I tried before.
But dojo core libraries and some dijit core classes will work well because it is used in dojox.mobile.

> -Have all the API been tested on variety of devices ? Do we have any reference document listing out the findings ?

It is described in release note... but it is too old.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/1.7.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/1.8.html

> -Lets say a particular widget is available in both dijit and dojox.mobile. What are the guidelines around choosing one of these

dijit parts are not tested in mobile devices I think.

Comment: Thanks !! An additional question on similar lines :-
The tutorials page lists a number of fantastic techniques :-
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/
Can I use any of these in my Dojo Mobile application ? What are the guidelines around that ?

My questions originate from the fact that  Dojo does not have a clearly separated API for mobile applications like SenchaTouch does (SenchaTouch API are clearly separate from EXTJS API).